Angular HTML doesn't refresh properly upon input data change
Inside my angular application I have an asset creator component that I want to use for creating, displaying and editing THREE.js 3D models.
I wanted to have a tree-view list to display the nested groups of meshes that make up the currently selected model and another list where you can select the model you want to edit. Upon selecting a model, the tree-view list should update to display the nested mesh groups of that model. Although the container component of the tree-view recognized the data change, the tree-view branch components that make up the tree-view itself did not.
Asset creator component:
html:
<div class="scene-container">
    <arpeajy-scene [mode]="'assetCreator'"></arpeajy-scene>
</div>
<div class="editor-tree-view-container">
    <arpeajy-tree-view *ngIf="currentAsset" [context]="'assetCreator'" [name]="currentAsset.name" [data]="currentAsset.template"></arpeajy-tree-view>
</div>
<div class="assets-list-container">
    <div>
        All assets:
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="assets.length > 0">
        <button *ngFor="let asset of assets" (click)="onClickSelectAsset(asset)">
            {{ asset.name }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

typescript:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'arpeajy-asset-creator',
  templateUrl: './asset-creator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asset-creator.component.scss']
})
export class AssetCreatorComponent implements OnInit {

  currentAsset: any
  assets: any[] = []

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const jsonUrl = 'assets/arpeajy-assets/assets3D.json';

    this.http.get(jsonUrl).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('JSON data:', data);
      console.log('JSON data:', data.assets);
      this.assets = data.assets;
    });
  }

  onClickSelectAsset(asset: any) {
    this.currentAsset = asset;
  }
}

Tree-view component:
html:
<div>
    Asset: {{ name }}
</div>
<arpeajy-tree-view-branch [context]="context" [data]="data"></arpeajy-tree-view-branch>

typescript:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'arpeajy-tree-view',
  templateUrl: './tree-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree-view.component.scss']
})
export class TreeViewComponent {

  @Input() context: string
  @Input() name: string
  @Input() data: any
}

Tree-view branch component:
html:
<div>
    {{ offsetLeft }}<button>{{ name }}</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="childObjects.length > 0">
    {{ offsetLeft }}<button (click)="onClickToggleExpansion()">Expand {{ name }}</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="expand">
    <div *ngFor="let object of childObjects">
        <arpeajy-tree-view-branch [context]="context" [data]="object" [offsetLeft]="offsetLeft + '-+'"></arpeajy-tree-view-branch>
    </div>
</div>

typescript:
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'arpeajy-tree-view-branch',
  templateUrl: './tree-view-branch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree-view-branch.component.scss']
})
export class TreeViewBranchComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() context: string
  @Input() data: any
  @Input() offsetLeft: string = ""
  name: string
  childObjects: any[] = [];
  expand: Boolean = false

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this.data.name;

    if (typeof this.data === "object" && this.data !== null) {

      // Check if the flag is set
      if (this.data.expandable && this.data.expandable.includes(this.context)) {

        // Iterate over the keys and store key-value pairs in children array
        Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
          
          if (key !== "expandable" && key !== "name") { // Exclude the flag itself

            let value = this.data[key];
            if (value !== null && typeof value === "object") {

              if(Array.isArray(value)) {
                value.forEach((element) => {

                  if (element !== null && typeof element === "object") {
                    this.childObjects.push(element);
                  }
                });

              } else {
                this.childObjects.push(value);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if ('data' in changes) {
      console.log('Data changed:', this.data);
    }
  }

  onClickToggleExpansion() {
    this.expand = !this.expand;
  }
}

What I did and what happened:
I pressed one of the buttons in the asset creator component to select an asset (for example Rock 1) by using the onClickSelectAsset method. This caused a correct tree-view to be generated. So far so good.
Then I pressed the button for a different asset (Tree 1). The div element inside the tree-view component that displays the name of the current asset is successfully updated and now instead of "Rock 1" it says "Tree 1". The root tree-view branch also seems to receive the new data as the ngOnChanges method inside tree-view-branch.component.ts correctly logs
"Data changed: {name: 'Group 0 TREE', expandable: Array(1), groups: Array(1)}"
in the browser console.
However, no data change was detected in any of the child branches as "Group 1 TREE" etc were not logged in the browser console (if I expanded the nested groups in the tree-view before selecting the Tree 1 asset. Otherwise those child components obviously wouldn't exist in the first place).
Also, the displayed buttons still said "Group 0 ROCK" etc.


This is the json file I use for testing if you need context on what the data looks like:
{
    "assets": [
        {
            "name": "Rock 1",
            "expandable": ["assetCreator"],
            "template": {
                "name": "Group 0 ROCK",
                "expandable": ["assetCreator"],
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "name": "Group 1 ROCK",
                        "expandable": ["assetCreator"],
                        "groups": [
                            {
                                "name": "Group 1.1 ROCK",
                                "expandable": ["assetCreator"],
                                "meshes": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Mesh 1.1.1",
                                        "geometry": ["box", [1, 1, 1]],
                                        "texture": "/assets/arpeajy-assets/test-texture.png",
                                        "materialType": "Lambert",
                                        "transform": [0, 0, 0],
                                        "rotation": [0, 0, 0]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Mesh 1.1.2",
                                        "geometry": ["box", [1, 1, 1]],
                                        "texture": "/assets/arpeajy-assets/test-texture.png",
                                        "materialType": "Lambert",
                                        "transform": [1, 0, 0],
                                        "rotation": [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "meshes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Mesh 1.1",
                                "geometry": ["box", [1, 1, 1]],
                                "texture": "/assets/arpeajy-assets/test-texture.png",
                                "materialType": "Lambert",
                                "transform": [0, 0, 0],
                                "rotation": [0, 0, 0]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Tree 1",
            "expandable": ["assetCreator"],
            "template": {
                "name": "Group 0 TREE",
                "expandable": ["assetCreator"],
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "name": "Group 1 TREE",
                        "expandable": ["assetCreator"],
                        "groups": [
                            {
                                "name": "Group 1.1 TREE",
                                "expandable": ["assetCreator"],
                                "meshes": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Mesh 1.1.1",
                                        "geometry": ["box", [1, 1, 1]],
                                        "texture": "/assets/arpeajy-assets/test-texture.png",
                                        "materialType": "Lambert",
                                        "transform": [0, 0, 0],
                                        "rotation": [0, 0, 0]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Mesh 1.1.2",
                                        "geometry": ["box", [1, 1, 1]],
                                        "texture": "/assets/arpeajy-assets/test-texture.png",
                                        "materialType": "Lambert",
                                        "transform": [1, 0, 0],
                                        "rotation": [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Group 1.2 TREE",
                                "expandable": ["assetCreator"],
                                "meshes": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Mesh 1.2.1",
                                        "geometry": ["box", [1, 1, 1]],
                                        "texture": "/assets/arpeajy-assets/test-texture.png",
                                        "materialType": "Lambert",
                                        "transform": [0, 0, 0],
                                        "rotation": [0, 0, 0]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Mesh 1.2.2",
                                        "geometry": ["box", [1, 1, 1]],
                                        "texture": "/assets/arpeajy-assets/test-texture.png",
                                        "materialType": "Lambert",
                                        "transform": [0, 0, 0],
                                        "rotation": [0, 0, 0]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "meshes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Mesh 1.1",
                                "geometry": ["box", [1, 1, 1]],
                                "texture": "/assets/arpeajy-assets/test-texture.png",
                                "materialType": "Lambert",
                                "transform": [0, 0, 0],
                                "rotation": [0, 0, 0]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Mesh 1.2",
                                "geometry": ["box", [1, 1, 1]],
                                "texture": "/assets/arpeajy-assets/test-texture.png",
                                "materialType": "Lambert",
                                "transform": [0, 0, 0],
                                "rotation": [0, 0, 0]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

I tried 2 things afterwards:
First I tried to set the currentAsset to null which did NOT solve the problem. The outcome was the same as before.
  onClickSelectAsset(asset: any) {
    this.currentAsset = null;
    this.currentAsset = asset;
  }

Then I tried it with a toggle. So every time an asset button is pressed while another asset is currently selected, it would instead just unselect the old asset. To actually select the new asset you would have to press the button again afterwards. This does work, but it's definitely not a good solution to this problem:
  onClickSelectAsset(asset: any) {
    if(this.currentAsset) {
      this.currentAsset = null;
    } else {
      this.currentAsset = asset;
    }
  }


I found the issue. I was under the assumption that the branches would all just update as soon as "data" changes but I eventually noticed that both the "name" as well as the "childObjects" I was using inside tree-view-branch.component.html were both set inside ngOnInit. They were based on the data attribute but wouldn't automatically get updated without the code inside ngOnInit. And since the root branch only received a change instead of getting re-initialized ngOnChanges was called instead of ngOnInit.
Therefore the simple solution was to put the code I had inside ngOnInit into a separate method and call it from both ngOnInit and ngOnChanges:
  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateData()
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.updateData()
  }

  updateData() {
    this.name = this.data.name;

    if (typeof this.data === "object" && this.data !== null) {

      // Check if the flag is set
      if (this.data.expandable && this.data.expandable.includes(this.context)) {

        // Iterate over the keys and store key-value pairs in children array
        Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
          
          if (key !== "expandable" && key !== "name") { // Exclude the flag itself

            let value = this.data[key];
            if (value !== null && typeof value === "object") {

              if(Array.isArray(value)) {
                value.forEach((element) => {

                  if (element !== null && typeof element === "object") {
                    this.childObjects.push(element);
                  }
                });

              } else {
                this.childObjects.push(value);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

EDIT: As pointed out by Anjula Ranasinghe I don't need to call this.updateData() in ngOnInit. Calling it in ngOnChanges is sufficient.

you probably don't need to call this.updateData() from both ngOnInit() and ngOnChanges(). calling from ngOnChanges() should be enough.

@AnjulaRanasinghe You are right. Only calling it in ngOnChanges is sufficient as well. Thanks
